# How to get single click event on image in column of DevExpress Grid Control using wpf?

Tags: devexpress, wpf-4.0, navigationbar, gridcontrol

I have Navigation bar control and one `NavBar` Group contains the grid control. I want to get the single click event on particular image which is in one column of grid control and on image click event I have to show the pop-up for some menu options.

I’m using the grid control’s preview mouse left button up event to get the click but it’s not working because the grid control resides in `Navbar` control.

Basically my problem is that I am not able to get the single click on image which is on column of grid control and grid column itself resides in one `Navbar` group of `NavBar` Control.

This [link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachment?fileOid=91bcadaa-036c-11e3-b699-00219b8b5047&fileName=NavBarDockPanelWpfApplication.zip) has my demo project.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen your demo project and i think the below code will solve your problem:-

private void gridControl1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

TableViewHitInfo hit = tableView1.CalcHitInfo(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);

```
if (hit.InRowCell) {

 gridControl1.View.FocusedRowHandle = hit.RowHandle;

   if (e.ClickCount == 1)

    {  
      if (e.XButton1 == MouseButtonState.Released)
        {

           if (hit.Column.FieldName == "number")
               {
                      var row = gridControl1.GetFocusedRow();
                      data d = (data)row;
                      MessageBox.Show(d.number.ToString());
                      x = d.number;
                    }
                    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                    {
                        if (hit.Column.FieldName == "image")
                        {
                            gridControl1.View.FocusedRowHandle = hit.RowHandle;
                            var row = gridControl1.GetFocusedRow();
                            data d = (data)row;
                            x = d.number;

                            popup.StaysOpen = true;
                            popup.IsEnabled = true;
                            popup.IsOpen = true;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```